# passing value of option button to query MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In Microsoft Acces 2016 I have a contacts Table where contacts can be either true or false (one field in the table). On the main form I want to add a button "ButtonOne" that shows these contacts in a new form, and I want to add a valuebutton where they can tick it to become true, the default is false. This value of the valuebutton should be passed into a query's WHERE condition and displayed on the new form that opens when the user presses the ButtonOne. What I have found in other posts is this macro below, but that doesn't give me what I want:

[Forms]![FormName]![ValueOptionButton]

Any ideas?
This is an edited version of my original question

Comment: Which version of Access?

Comment: 2016, added to the message

Comment: This makes no sense. If the radio button is supposed to be filter parameter, why are you populating a field with its value? Is Column3 Yes/No field you want to apply parameter to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestions in [this link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/access-cookbook/0596000847/ch01s02.html)? This works if you're willing to open a query instead of a form, and have your ValueOptionButton on the main form instead of the opened one. I suppose this should also work if you based your form off of a query.

I tested it on a form of my own that has a radio button by adding a button that opened a query with criteria like what you're describing and got the desired result.

The syntax for your form reference looks right to me. How exactly are you implementing the query into your opened form?